# how to convert 'object or icons' to "shape" to change color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, icon, photoshop-effects

[image]

how to convert icon to shape to change instant color in Photoshop

Comment: It would be helpful if you were a little more descriptive not only with what you are trying to achieve but also what program version you are using.

Comment: First pick a software you are trying to do this in. I'm assuming Photoshop based off the image. You would need to make it into a shape  and then as a shape layer you can apply new colors to it.

Comment: Expand the icon to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **redraw** it as a vector layer. Or use some vector application to auto-trace your original raster image, then import the result back into Photoshop.

There's no automated method of doing what you want within Photoshop

Comment: You could also include that you could color it even if it is not a shape but converting the color into a mask for a fill layer for example. Just covering the bases here.